# Google Maps Embed into Site without Popup window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I'm using the following code to embed a Google map into my page:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Chicago+IL&z=15&iwloc=A&output=embed
```

This works fine, but when it loads this it automatically opens up a box with the address and get directions etc. Is there anyway to load this without having the popup window load as well?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I just had to change the value of `iwloc` to be `near`. So now the embed URL looks like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Chicago+IL&z=15&iwloc=near&output=embed
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This allows the pop up window to not appear.

Comment: thanks, my snippet did not have `iwloc` at all, so i just added as above, and that worked